# Function parameter not carried to switch statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I've been making a basic game but I've encountered a problem while trying to make a function that would be usable among several occasions by using the switch statement. The output I keep getting when I run the function is the default code block. Here's some sample code:

```
function battle(boss) {
    slaying = true;
    while(slaying) {
        switch(boss) {
            case 'boss1':
                console.log('This is' + boss1.name);
                break;
            case 'boss2':
                console.log('This is' + boss2.name);
                break;
            default:
                console.log('No boss');
                break;
        }
        slaying = false;
    }
}

function Boss(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var boss1 = new Boss('boss1');
var boss2 = new Boss('boss2');

battle(boss1);
```

Comment: `boss` is an object instance; `switch(boss.name) ` or override `toString()`

Comment: @alex-k Ahh yes that helped thanks